# ¿Unir 2 listas simplemente enlazadas a una lista doblemente enlazada?

Tags: c++, lista, estructuras-de-datos

El problema es el siguiente (Estoy utilizando clases):
Tengo dos listas simples que las quiero unir para que al final sea una lista doblemente enlazada.

Lo que he intentado hacer es:

Utilizar el puntero sig para la lista 1 y el puntero ant para la lista 2. Al final con un ciclo tratar que el puntero de la lista 2 (ant) se vaya acomodando entre los nodos

```
    void unir()
   {
    planta *ind=Lista1;
    planta *ind2=Lista2, *antes;
    for (;ind->sig!=NULL;ind=ind->sig)
    {      
        antes=ind;
        ind=ind->sig;
        for (;ind2->ant!=NULL;ind=ind->ant)
        {
            Lista2=Lista2->ant;
            ind2->ant=antes;
        }
    }
    Lista2=ind;
   }
```

Ese es el metodo

```
class planta
{ 
private:
planta *Lista1, *Lista2, *sig, *ant;
int No_emp, Productividad;
string Nombre, Departamento;
public:
planta()
{
    No_emp=0;
    Lista1=Lista2=sig=ant=Unida1=Unida2=NULL;
    Nombre=Departamento=" ";
}
};
```

Esa es mi clase con su constructor